# java: Scanner asks for an extra value when using useDelimiter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, csv

So I wanna create this program that stores 4 values. the first one being string and the remaining 3 being integers. However, when i enter 4 values and press enter, i get an error `java.util.InputMismatchException` but when I enter 5 values, i get the result for my for values. for example lets say i input the following values:

```
Japan,1,2,3
```

I will get the `java.util.InputMismatchException` error. And if I enter the following values:-

```
Japan,1,2,3,4
```

I get the output as I want:-

```
Japan,1,2,3
```

Why is this happening? Here is my code

```
public class satisfaction {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner src= new Scanner(System.in);
        src.useDelimiter("\\,|\\n");
        String name=src.next();
        int a=src.nextInt();
        int b=src.nextInt();
        int c=src.nextInt();
        System.out.println(name+","+a+","+b+","+c);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this a bit myself, and I think the `\n` in the pattern is not matching the line ending used by your console.

For me, I had to use `\r\n` instead, but you could also use `System.lineSeparator()` e.g. like this:

```
src.useDelimiter(",|" + System.lineSeparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

The way it's written, it needs another comma at the end of the input. I would recommend checking the string to make sure it ends in a comma, and if not, append one.

I believe that if you enter `Japan,1,2,3,` it will give you the output you want.

Comment: yea but i dont want to put a coma in the end. isnt there anything else i can do?

Comment: Yes you can programmatically add a comma. There also might be a way to change the delimeter but I'm not sure